# Connecting Samsung S7 to AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, samsung-galaxy

I like to start my app directly on Samsung S7 with AndroidStudio.

I have already enabled debugging mode in the developer option by tapping 7 times on build number, but still I don't see the device when starting the app and getting the "Select Deployment Target" Dialog.

What else do I have to do ?

Comment: What operating system you are using?

Comment: Windows 8.1......

Comment: install [this](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows).

Comment: install http://adbdriver.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In developer options at bottom of setings menu, ensure USB debugging is ticked. Then start again, restart windows and S7 to make sure and try again. With one of my devices, tapping seven times enabled developer mode, but the debugging options was not selected by default and had to be manually selected from developer options after they were enabled.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this did the trick. I also restarted windows and my device. Not sure this was really needed, but it works now. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

Install necessary drivers from this [site](http://adbdriver.com/). Then connect your device with debugging enabled, your device will prompt a dialog for permission, click ok.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows, i have sometimes needed to "reconnect" the device. Particularly when switching between the device and emulator.

To do that, find the folder in the sdk that you have downloaded for adb.exe
In that folder, start up a command prompt and try "adb reconnect". This usually works for me. Sometimes, I have also had to revoke the debugging permissions and then reenable them from the developer settings on the phone...

Note that this S7 Is the most problematic phone I have with this issue. I have about 6 other development phones, and this is the worst for connection issues. Otherwise, I think the phone is great.